# Добавление в корзину одинаковых товаров с разными параметрами

Tags: php, корзина

Необходимо написать PHP скрипт с возможностью добавления нескольких одинаковы товаров с разными параметрами.

Нужно сделать так же (параметр "диоптрии")
http://dostavim-linzi.ru/catalog/1DayAcuvueOasys

Сайт полностью самописный и данные корзины хранятся в $_SESSION в виде массива ('id_товара' => 'кол-во')

Как вообще можно реализовать данную возмо Если не сам ответ, то хоть ссылочку дайте) Уже второй день пытаюсь ответ найти, но всё без толку

Comment: Каждая запись в таблице покупок содержит в себе ид товара и ид доп параметров в отдельном поле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в общем, то как-то вот так (см схему). Есть набор товаров (молоко, сметана). Есть набор характеристик товаров (жирность, например). Для каждого товара прописываются все комбинации с его характеристиками (многие ко многим).  У каждой такой комбинации (Молоко - жирность, Сметана - жирность) есть значения, которые перечислены  в отдельной таблице "Детальная характеристика товара": для молока это 2.5, 3.2. Для сметаны 18, 24, 35. Клиент делает заказ на товар. А отдельно для этого товара храним выбранные им характеристики.
Схема упрощённая - марки товаров, производители и т.п. и т.д. - это всё надо разность. Для конкретно линз (можно ведь заказать различающиеся линзы по характеристикам для левого и правого глаза) тоже нужно городить. С названием таблиц\сущностей тоже не сильно парился.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сделать так, как делают практически все разрабы движков интернет-магазинов. Есть товар, а есть к нему конфигурация. Связь один ко многим. И в зависимости от выбранной конфигурации получается товар. Просто итоговую корзину делать таки с учетом и товаров и конфигураций.